# Apply style to only first level of td tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to apply a Class' style to only ONE level of td tags?

```
<style>.MyClass td {border: solid 1px red;}</style>

<table class="MyClass">
  <tr>
    <td>
      THIS SHOULD HAVE RED BORDERS
    </td>
    <td>
      THIS SHOULD HAVE RED BORDERS
      <table><tr><td>THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE ANY</td></tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 260, accepted):

> Is there a way to apply a Class' style to only ONE level of td tags?

Yes<sup>*</sup>:

```
.MyClass>tbody>tr>td { border: solid 1px red; }
```

But! The ‘`>`’ direct-child selector does not work in IE6. If you need to support that browser (which you probably do, alas), all you can do is select the inner element separately and un-set the style:

```
.MyClass td { border: solid 1px red; }
.MyClass td td { border: none; }
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Note that the first example references a `tbody` element not found in your HTML. It *should* have been in your HTML, but browsers are generally ok with leaving it out... they just add it in behind the scenes.

Comment: i shudder to remember a world where we had to debug for IE6. This post brought back chills..

Answer (score 29):

how about using the CSS :first-child pseudo-class:

```
.MyClass td:first-child { border: solid 1px red; }
```

Comment: That won't work. This selects all `td` children in the children tree of `.MyClass` which are first of their containing element, and thus will also style the inner `td`.

Comment: how does this have so many upvotes?  `:first-child` will definitely not have the effect OP is looking for.

Answer (score 9):

This style:

```
table tr td { border: 1px solid red; }
td table tr td { border: none; }
```

gives me:

[this http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/4477/borders.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/4477/borders.png)

However, using a class is probably the right approach here.

Comment: Using a class on every single td element may be a little redundant, you'd probably use a class on the containing table element, and then you'd still have to exclude second levels of tables - ie your first example is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Just make a selector for tables inside a MyClass.

```
.MyClass td {border: solid 1px red;}
.MyClass table td {border: none}
```

(To generically apply to all inner tables, you could also do `table table td`.)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to set the width of the first column of the table, and I found this worked (in FF7) - the first column is 50px wide:

```
#MyTable>thead>tr>th:first-child { width:50px;}
```

where my markup was

```
<table id="MyTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Col1</th>
   <th scope="col">Col2</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try

```
table tr td { color: red; }
table tr td table tr td { color: black; }
```

Or

```
body table tr td { color: red; }
```

where 'body' is a selector for your table's parent

But classes are most likely the right way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

I think, It will work.

```
.Myclass tr td:first-child{ }

 or 

.Myclass td:first-child { }
```

Comment: Does the first one select the first `td` of every row and the second one only select the first `td` of the page?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter you are basically correct about the first one.  In general, `td:first-child` selects any `td` element that is the first element under its parent (no matter what its parent is).  The first one `tr td:first-child` adds the condition that the `td` must also be nested below a `tr` (at any level, not necessarily direct descendant).  `tr > td:first-child` selects a `td` that is the first element directly under a `tr`.  So ultimately `:first-child` has nothing to do with a solution to the OP's question and this answer is incorrect.