# Apply style to cells of first row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

It should be very simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a table like this :

```
<table class="category_table">
 <tr><td> blabla 1</td><td> blabla 2 </td></tr>
 <tr><td> blabla 3 </td><td> blabla 4 </td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to make `td` tags of first `tr` row have `vertical-align`. But not the second row.

```
.category_table td{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613284/css-apply-style-to-first-level-of-td-only

Comment: Yeah I have seen that page before asking a question, It wasn't working.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use `tr:first-child` to take the first `tr`:

```css
.category_table tr:first-child td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

If you have nested tables, and you don't want to apply styles to the inner rows, add some child selectors so only the top-level `td`s in the first top-level `tr` get the styles:

```css
.category_table > tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried this before, It's not working. Not sure why.

Comment: I don't know either. I have 100% confidence that this works for all major browsers.

Comment: When I compare `td` tags of first and second row in FireBug, I can see the first row Inherited the style but the second row has not. I don't know why the second row is vertically aligned !?

Comment: Then it's probably a default style. I'm not familiar with default table styles.

Comment: I have gone a little deeper with FireBug. I think I found the problem. Actually inside my `td` tags of second row, I have table in there. It seems the table inside cells of second row Inherited the style.

Comment: ... and this is why you need to show complete code samples and not miss any important details. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for that. I will keep that in mind. OK I tried  your Updated answer but none of `td`s are v-aligned anymore. If you wish I can show the full code. I am just worried that you will get confused. Because the lang is not english too.

Comment: Found the culprit. I should have added a `tbody` before `> tr:first-child`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5568877/106224) for an explanation.

Comment: @Konstantin Pereyaslov: If your HTML doesn't match what the OP has, that's the first place to look.

Comment: @BoltClock yes it turns out it works fine, I wanted to match first column, not first row so I had to use `:first child` after `td`, not `tr`, totally my bad (deleting original comment now)

Comment: @Konstantin Pereyaslov: Ah. Glad you solved it then! Also, I noticed a downvote that coincided with your comment - if it was yours, feel free to remove it as I've edited my post.

Comment: `:first-child` is better or `:nth-child(1)`? Which one is better in old browsers?

Comment: @Sajad: `:first-child` is better. However if you have styles that depend on other `:nth-child()` values, use `:nth-child(1)` so it degrades consistently. (I might post a self-answered question about this.)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work:

```
.category_table tr:first-child td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Below works for first `tr` of the table under `thead`

```
table thead tr:first-child {
   background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

And this works for the first `tr` of `thead` and `tbody` both:

```
table thead tbody tr:first-child {
   background: #f2f2f2;
}
```