# Apply CSS rule to only the first <td> in <tr>'s WITHOUT assigning a class/id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613284/css-apply-style-to-first-level-of-td-only), it's not what I need here..

I need something like

```
table.mytable tr first-td's { border: 1px solid black; }
```

for

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
<td>This has the border</td>
<td>no border</td>
<td>no border</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>This has the border</td>
<td>no border</td>
<td>no border</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>This has the border</td>
<td>no border</td>
<td>no border</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If this is impossible just let me know and I'll be sad.

Javascript/jQuery is acceptable if it's needed to get the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It´s possible:

Use in your CSS

```
.mytable tr td:first-child  { border: 1px solid black; }​
```

[Try Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vpnka/)

Comment: thank you kindly. I noticed td:last-child also works, but td:second-child does not. Ah well

Comment: @khanahk: For numbers other than first/last you can use e.g. `:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: ah yes, there are even `odd` and `even` params you can put in `:nth-child()` with CSS3. Good stuff

Answer (score 8):

```
table.mytable tr td:first-child { border: 1px solid black; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child

Works in jQuery too ( http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ ):

```
$('table.mytable tr td:first-child')
```

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% cross-browser, but support is good enough. See http://caniuse.com/#search=:first-child

```
table.mytable tr td:first-child
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:first-of-type`, but it's not available on older browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/R9qE3/.

You could also pick the right elements through jQuery (for cross-browser support), but you would need to update the state when you add `td`s or move them around.

Answer (score 3):

```
table.mytable tr:first-child {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery "nth child" http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

It would be something like:

```
$("table.mytable tr::nth-child(1)")  //do w/e you need to do here.
```