# How can I get only the first level element from an element if all it has is a tag

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get only the first level element from an element if all it has is a tag? I have the below html and just want to get all the "tr" tags from the first level of found "tr"s. Not the ones within the "tr" tag.

```
<tbody>
 <tr> // I want this
  <td>
  <td>
   <div>
    <table>
      <colgroup span="9">
        <tbody>
          <tr> // Don't want this
           <td>
 <tr> // I want this
  <td>
  <td>
   <div>
    <table>
```

etc.

Comment: tbody > tr  this will select the first level tr

Comment: `/tbody/tr` - with one slash only children

Comment: @lotfiolakehal `tbody > tr` will select *all* `tr` elements that are direct children of **any** `tbody` element. The OP wants to exclude the nested table.

Comment: @splash58 `/tbody/tr` is not valid CSS syntax.

Comment: @ScottMarcus there is tag `xpath`

Comment: @Scott Marcus so he can simply giv it a class .tbodyclass > tr

Comment: @lotfiolakehal He states in the title of his question that he needs to be able to access the elements using only the HTML tag. Therefore, he can't "simply" add a class. Very often CSS designers don't have the ability to modify the HTML that they are styling. Given that the question is tagged with "selenium", it would appear that this is such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but first you will need to set the style you want on all rows and then then reset the nested table's rows back to their default style.

```css
.table, td { border:1px solid black; }

/* First set the style you want, but set it on all rows. */
tr { background-color:yellow; }

/* Then reset the nested table's rows back to their default style. */
table table tr { background-color:white; }
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use classes to select the elements.

Edit:

There's another post with the same question.([Apply style to only first level of td tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613284/apply-style-to-only-first-level-of-td-tags))

Use 
`.MyClass>tbody>tr>td { border: solid 1px red; }`

Comment: And yet, the question states that all there is to go on is the tag structure. Sometimes, CSS designers can't change the HTML.

Comment: Regarding your edit: The OP states that they only have the HTML structure to go on. The solution you point to requires a class be added to the top level table, which is not always a possibility for CSS designers.

Answer (score -1):

if you use jQuery, you can target it using something like:

```
$("tbody > tr").html()
```

This will select the `tr` that immediately follows the `tbody`

To get the next one you would want to look for its siblings.

Comment: Calling `.val()` on a `tr` element seems kind of silly, since it's meant to get the value of a form element...

Comment: It is not generally appropriate to offer a solution that involves technologies that were not tagged in the question.

Comment: Additionally, your solution will find every `tr` element that is a child of a `tbody` element, which does not solve the OPs question. He wants to exclude the nested `tbody` in the query - yours won't do that.